# URL .HTACCESS LINK SETTING

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a link
https://example.com/article.php?article_link=10-scientists-who-made-the-dropsy-vaccine

i want this link to have a url like
https://example.com/article/10-scientists-who-made-the-dropsy-vaccine

where the last part of the link i.e 10-scientists-who-made-the-dropsy-vaccine is dynamic and can be anything

How can i do this???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with your htaccess . Open your `.htaccess` file and put the following rule :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^article/(.+)$ /article.php?article_link=$1 [L,NC]
```